# Trying to get property 'error' of non-object in register.php on line 41

Tags: php, sql, ionic3

> Notice: Trying to get property 'username' of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mobile\login_register\register.php on line 25
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'userpass' of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mobile\login_register\register.php on line 26
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'mobile' of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mobile\login_register\register.php on line 27
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'email' of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mobile\login_register\register.php on line 28
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'error' of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mobile\login_register\register.php on line 41 "Error:
>   INSERT INTO users (username, userpass, mobile, email) VALUES ('', '',
>   '', '') "

**register.php**

```
    require "dbconnect.php";

    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    if (isset($data)) {
        $request = json_decode($data);
        $username = $request->username;
        $userpass = $request->userpass;
        $mobile = $request->mobile;
        $email = $request->email;

    }

$username = stripslashes($username);
$userpass = stripslashes($userpass);
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, userpass, mobile, email) VALUES ('$username', '$userpass', '$mobile', '$email')";

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $response= "Registration successfull";

} else {
    $response= "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $db->error;
}
        echo json_encode($response);
```

> line 41 $response= "Error: " . $sql . "
> " . $con->error;

**dbconnect.php**

```
<?php

  define('HOST','localhost');

  define('USER','root');

  define('PASS','');

  define('DB', '8990qacheck');

  $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

   if (!$con){
      die("Error in connection" . mysqli_connect_error()) ;
  }

?>
```

the problem is just here its no worth showing the ts file

Comment: Your connection is called `$con`, not `$db`

Comment: You haven't shown us the rest of the lines so we can't really tell what is causing those errors, but it's probably something similar.

Comment: can you show the connection variable..`$con`

Comment: <?php

  define('HOST','localhost');

  define('USER','root');

  define('PASS','');

  define('DB', '8990qacheck');

  $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

   if (!$con){
      die("Error in connection" . mysqli_connect_error()) ;
  }

?>

Comment: @nick i changed it to $con and give me the same error output

Comment: Well, it will have fixed the error on line 41, but as I said, you haven't shown enough code to debug the others.

Comment: i will show you in the next post

Comment: @Nick i updated my question since i can only post another question 90 minutes after this post.

Comment: So then it looks like your `json_decode` failed.

Comment: Choose object-oriented or procedural mysqli sytax ...not both.  Crack open the php manual and study how to feed the connection variable to the mysqli functions.  Prepared statements are worth learning too.  You aren't databasing unencrypted passwords, are you?